# Pushing data to an array inside another array with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json

I made an array for a raffle system using node.js and discord.js which has this data set.
`[{"author":"Name","rafflename":"RAFFLE","amount":"10","entries":"[]"}]`

When someone tries to enter the raffle I'd like to make another JSON array inside the `entries` tag.

The problem i face is when i use `raffles[0].entries.push({ 'username': 'example', 'user_id': '1' });`

It returns an error:  `raffles[0].entries.push is not a function`

I assume this is because it is looking for the array `raffles[0].entries.push` which does not exist. But I've only ever used the push command. So I am not sure how to fix this issue.

Comment: "[]" is a string, not an array

Comment: I can change that, So how would one make that an array?

Comment: `[]` not `"[]"` is all, while your at it, probably want to change `"10"` to `10`

Comment: You can use like this:
[{"author":"Name","rafflename":"RAFFLE","amount":10,"entries":[]}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your entries [] out of double quotes, i.e. Use "entries" :[]

You are trying to push to a string instead of array

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast entries to Array first.

```js
const raffles = [{"author":"Name","rafflename":"RAFFLE","amount":"10","entries":"[]"}]
// cast entries to Array
raffles[0].entries = JSON.parse(raffles[0].entries)
// now you can push them
raffles[0].entries.push('test')
console.log(raffles)
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't working because you have "" around the properties inside of your object.  you can fix this by either removing the "" or doing this:

`raffles[0]['entries'].push(//your code here);`

When properties of an object are strings (i.e. when they have quotes around them) you must access that property using "dot notation"

eg:

```
var object = {"property":"five"};
console.log(object["property"]); //prints 'five'

console.log(object.property); //throws an error
```

Answer (score 0):

Format Your Array according to @Bibberty  Comment and do operation

```js
raffles=rafale=[{"author":"Name","rafflename":"RAFFLE","amount":10,"entries":[]}]

raffles[0].entries.push({ 'username': 'example', 'user_id': 1 });

console.log(raffles)
```